# What is Drake equation?

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, universe

I was reading an article on aliens, where I found something called [Drake equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_equation). I tried to understand it, but just couldn't get it in my head, as I belong to class 11. So, can anyone explain me it in simple language, in terms that I'm capable of understanding?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/384/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, it is: how many aliens could we meet?

More specifically: The Drake Equation is a way of predicting how many intelligent species there might be in the universe and the likelihood of them contacting us.

There are a lot of things that can change the number of aliens we can expect to find.  So we use what we know about the universe so far and keeping multiplying the various factors to get some sort of idea (no one knows if it is accurate, but it is nice to have some sort of idea).

The factors include:

- How many stars are there? (because we think all life would need to be
  near a star).
- How many planets are there? (because life obviously needs some place
  to live and it can't live on a star)
- How many of those planets have water and air? (i.e. habitable
  planets)
- How many of those airy, watery planets contain aliens?
- How many of those aliens are clever?
- How many clever aliens invent radio or some other way of
  communicating?

And most importantly:

- How long do they try to communicate? (because if they blow themselves
  up in a war or give up trying to say hello then they are never going
  to be found by our telescopes).

The universe has been around such a long time that it's possible aliens nearby have lived and died long ago and we are going to find younger aliens somewhere else, but not for millions of years. etc. etc.

Of course, we can't know the answers to some of these questions, but we do know the answers to others and we get more accurate and more information all the time.  Eventually we'll have enough info to make an educated guess and that will be an exciting time indeed!

Comment: It's not a method but rather a probabilistic (though very hard) estimation.

Comment: I was using the word in the non-mathematical sense (for year 11), but I can see how that confuses.  I'll change it.

Comment: +1; Otherwise it is intuitive for OP, at least I think:)

Comment: I would guess the Drake equation might be outdated given all the astrophysics data gathered since it was first conceived. Structural assumptions have probably changed. So has anyone improved on drake?

Comment: @docscience I asked a similar question a while ago on Quora, and the response I got was that the Drake equation is sufficiently broad that most adjustments are encompassed by one of the main variables. (I was asking about tidal forces and whether they are factored in).  I think the 'real' models have vastly more complicated equations underneath each of the 7 variables we see in the popular version.

Comment: *"The Drake Equation is a way of **predicting** how many [...]."* (emphasis mine) A less charitable phrase would be "justifying a wild-ass-guess about". Not that there is anything wrong with the process (though the particular factorization into terms in necessarily arbitrary), just that this thing has never had anything like a rigorous use, and won't until we have so much statistical data about biological processes that we'll already know the actual answer.

Comment: @dmckee Ha!  You're dead right.  Perhaps 'framework for forming estimates' would be more acceptable.  Apparently Drake only even meant it to stimulate debate and, in that regard, he has succeeded.  I see the Drake equation like a combination lock and we're gradually adding known values in the parameter-slots.  Eventually we'll unlock the mystery (or it'll be too late and we'll know anyway, either by looking or being told) :)

Comment: @Astravagrant I'm not 11 year old, I study in class 11, so my age is 16!

Comment: @Aneek I said 'year 11' not '11 year old' :)

Comment: @Astravagrant oops sorry, misunderstood your comment! ;)